# Remove words where the first character is letter and the rest numbers

Tags: r

I would like to remove all words from a string that starts with a letter followed by numbers and ending either with semicolon or a space.
For example, given the string

```
x <- "Z1; D49;  Pay-What-You-Want; A1; Moods; Weather; Social norms, K20"
```

The desired output is

```
Pay-What-You-Want; Moods; Weather; Social norms;
```

Thank you

Comment: Are your data actually one long string, or a vector of strings?

Comment: In your example data "Social norms" is followed by a comma, should that be replaced by a semi-colon or is it just a typo?

Comment: No, it's not a typo. Optimally it should contain a semicolon but most important is to get rid of the words with one letter and numbers. The data is a vector of strings but I can handle that problem.

Comment: you removed `K20` but it doesn't end with a semicolon or space

Comment: `gsub("([ ]+)?[A-Za-z]\\d+([; ]+)?","",x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` like:

```
x <- "Z1; D49;  Pay-What-You-Want; A1; Moods; Weather; Social norms, K20"

gsub("\\b[a-zA-Z]\\d+[ ;]*", "", gsub(",", ";", x))
#[1] "Pay-What-You-Want; Moods; Weather; Social norms; "

gsub("\\b[a-zA-Z]\\d+[ ;]", "", x)  #Does what the question asked for
#[1] "   Pay-What-You-Want;  Moods; Weather; Social norms, K20"
```

`\\b`..Word boundary
`[a-zA-Z]`..starts with a letter
`\\d+`..followed by numbers
`[ ;]`..ending either with semicolon or a space

Answer (score 4):

So let's make it a "vector o strings" because it's easier to work with such a value than with a single character value.

```
# if commas should become semicolons then use gsub("
x <- gsub("[,]", ";", "Z1; D49;  Pay-What-You-Want; A1; Moods; Weather; Social norms, K20")
# make it a vector
x2 <- trimws(scan(text=x, what="", sep=";"))
#If you want it to be one string (which seems odd but doable:
(x3 <- paste( x2[!grepl("^[[:alpha:]](\\d)+",x2)] , collapse="; ") )
#[1] "Pay-What-You-Want; Moods; Weather; Social norms"
# Or
(x4 <- x2[!grepl("^[[:alpha:]](\\d)+",x2)] )
#[1] "Pay-What-You-Want" "Moods"             "Weather"           "Social norms"
```

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of your comments is that you have a character vector, each element of which is a semicolon-delimited (with some commas) string. If that’s right, then using stringr functions within `sapply()`:

```
library(stringr)

sapply(
  str_split(x, "(,|;)\\s+"),
  \(.x) str_c(.x[!str_detect(.x, "^\\w\\d+$")], collapse = "; ")
)
# [1] "Pay-What-You-Want; Moods; Weather; Social norms"
```

Or using base R:

```
sapply(
  strsplit(x, "(,|;)\\s+"),
  \(.x) paste(.x[!grepl("^\\w\\d+$", .x)], collapse = "; ")
)
```